# __init__() missing positional argument when calling class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, arguments, typeerror

I am trying to figure out why the **init**() is missing one argument, in this case speed when 3 arguments have been given in the line `plane = Mywork.__init__( 'boeing', 747, 890)`

Here is the full code, I presume I didnt do something right about the first argument just being put down as a string and not specifying that anywhere even though I used **str**?

All I want to happen is for the code to execute def **str** and run.

Code:

```
class Mywork(object):

    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, speed): #Aircraft
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.speed = speed

    def __str__(self):
        return 'This is a {self.manufacturer} {self.model}'.format(self=self)

    def run(self):
        print('Works')
        print(self.__str__())

plane = Mywork.__init__( 'boeing', 747, 890)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Mywork()
```

Comment: Show the stack trace. Which line has the error? `MyWork()` certainly won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `__init__` directly without first creating an instance to pass as the first argument. The following is legal, though no one would ever write code like this:

```
plane = Mywork.__new__(Mywork, 'boeing', 747, 980)
Mywork.__init__(plane, 'boeing', 747, 980)
```

What you *want* is almost certainly

```
class Mywork(object):
    ...

plane = Mywork('boeing', 747, 890)
...
```

You also don't really ever call `__str__` explicitly; you let `str` do that when an instance of your class is passed as an argument.

```
print(self.__str__())  # No!
print(str(self))  # Better
print(self)  # Best; print() already calls str as necessary to convert its arguments
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    plane = Mywork('boeing', 747, 890)
    print(plane)
```

OUTPUT:

```
>>This is a boeing 747
```